# MySQL Filter Products Category AND & OR

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to filter results by category.
So from the ItemKeywords table below

```
SELECT prod_id FROM ItemKeywords 
WHERE (keyword_id=96 OR keyword_id=96) /* Metal category */
AND keyword_id=55 /* Center category */

WHERE (Rose Gold OR White Gold) 
AND Princess Cut
```

This Should only pull up 100657 and 102163

Either Rose Gold OR White Gold

But needs to be Princess Cut

```
== Keywords ==========================
|keyword_id   |KeywordName      |category
| 55          | Princess Cut    | Center
| 96          | Rose Gold       | Metal
| 102         | White Gold      | Metal
| 88          | Platinum        | Metal

== ItemKeywords ==========================
|keyword_id   |prod_id          |category
| 96          | 100657          | Metal
| 55          | 100657          | Center
| 102         | 102163          | Metal
| 55          | 102163          | Center
| 88          | 100686          | Metal
| 55          | 100686          | Center
```

I tried this

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.prod_id), p.header, p.image 
FROM tblproducts AS p 
JOIN ItemKeywords AS k1 ON k1.prod_id=p.prod_id AND k1.keyword_id=96 OR k1.keyword_id=101 
JOIN ItemKeywords AS k2 ON k2.prod_id=p.prod_id AND k2.keyword_id=55 
WHERE p.active=1
```

and this

```
SELECT DISTINCT(p.prod_id), p.header, p.image 
FROM ItemKeywords AS k JOIN tblproducts AS p ON k.prod_id=p.prod_id
WHERE p.active=1 AND p.retire=0 AND p.category_id=2 
AND k.keyword_id=55 AND k.keyword_id=102 OR k.keyword_id=101
```

And other. I can't seem  to figure this out.

Any insight would be great.

Thanks

Comment: you need parenthesis around your groups of conditions, just like in your top query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since you want to have two possible "keyword_id", you need to include table ItemKeyWords twice in your select. Once for the Metal Category and one more time for center Category.
2. Next you need to filter the results in the WHERE clause.

```html
SELECT DISTINCT(p.prod_id), p.header, p.image 
FROM tblproducts AS p 
JOIN ItemKeywords AS k1 ON k1.prod_id=p.prod_id
JOIN ItemKeywords AS k2 ON k2.prod_id=p.prod_id
WHERE p.active=1 AND p.retire=0 AND p.category_id=2 
AND (k1.keyword_id=96  OR k1.keyword_id=102) AND k2.keyword_id=55
```